# Want to make a slideshow with prerecorded audio

Tags: audio-recording, slideshow

I have a six-minute audio recording.  I want to add slides with Powerpoint or with something that will give me similar results.  Each slide needs to appear at a precise time.  I would like something free or inexpensive, since I don't contemplate doing this again.  I would not like to spend a lot of time learning new software.  I'm reasonably good at using Powerpoint, and I have made screencast presentations with Jing.  Ultimately the finished produce needs to go on the web.

**Edit**:

I found out that Powerpoint had the advantages that (a) I was already familiar with it, and (b) I was able to fill and format the slides with good control.  However, monkeying with the timing was rather tedious.  Next time I'd like to try something different.  Maybe Movie Maker.

Comment: Why not doing it in PowerPoint and exporting as video?

Comment: @YisroelTech - Thanks for responding.  If you know how to do this, could you outline the approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197969/powerpoint-to-create-slideshow-to-accompany-prerecorded-audio-file?

Comment: I would try outline it, but I'm not sure where your hardships are. If you create PowerPoint slideshows where are you stuck here. (it belongs here on Superuser and not on Stackoverflow)

Comment: @YisroelTech - Should I delete my question there and ask it at Superuser instead?  I'm confused, because there are other somewhat similar questions on Stackoverflow. // If my question is migrated, and you have already written an answer, your answer will go along for the ride. // I just have no idea how to do what I described.  I know how to add animation and audio to an individual slide, but I don't know how to connect slides and an existing audio recording.

Comment: I would say this belongs in Superuser since that is the help site for software (in you case PowerPoint), unlike Stackoverflow which is to create own code/software or Software Recommendations which is to find software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly what your need is, this can be easily done in PowerPoint.

### To Add the audio file to the slideshow:

1. On the **Insert** tab, select **Audio**, and then **Audio on My PC**.
2. In the file explorer, locate the music file you want to use and then select **Insert**.
3. On the **Playback** tab, select **Play across slides**, select **Start** -> "automatically," and check box next to "Hide During Show."

### Specify a time to advance to the next slide:

1. Select the slide that you want to set the timing for.
2. On the Transitions tab, in the Timing group, under Advance Slide, uncheck the **On Mouse Click** check box.
3. Select the **After** check box, and then type the number of minutes or seconds that you want into the associated text box.

### Save as video file:

1. Click the **File** menu and choose **Export** from the left pane.
2. From the Export options click on **Create a Video**.
3. Make sure **Use Recorded Timings and Narrations** is chosen from the 2nd drop down menu.
4. Click the **Create Video** button and save the file as MP4 to the location you want it.

Comment: But how do I time the slides to play at the right time?  (Too sleepy to move the question right now, sorry.)

Comment: @aparente001, is it the same timing for all the slides (let's say you want to divide 20 slides evenly between the six minutes playback), or each slide has a different duration it should appear?

Comment: No, not the same for each one.

Comment: Added that in my answer

Comment: Thank you very much.  How should I save or export so that I can conveniently embed this on a web page?  Also, what's a good way to send this to people by email?  Should I put it in google drive or youtube?  What if the other person doesn't have Powerpoint?

Comment: Saving as a video (mp4) file would be the best idea, this can be shared on Google Drive, YouTube, email (if the file size isn't too large), and any medium you want to. I added the steps to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create the slider first and then animate it without the music. Next I use Lightworks to edit and add the music. That's it. Even you can do this online.